# wordpress quiz creator responsive problem

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I am using a wordpress theme integrated quiz creator. in this creator, i add answers to the questions but in desktop apperance ,as below picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbWg1.png)

And I want it on the mobile appereance to look the same as the computer yet in the mobile answers is Sorting by 1 column. How do I sorting the answers in a row?

problem is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Ejo.png)

Comment: It's a css thing, force the width of the answers 33% each one don't let the 100% do it.

Comment: sir i do not have any css code skills or info, how do i do force the width %33(css code)

Comment: To do that you need css skills, if you want pass the url and and i'll tell you where to put it and everything.